# Can't bug report steam on Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: steam, 15.04

I did a `ubuntu-bug steam` (can't do `ubuntu bug -w` because steam won't start) and I get the following message:

```
The problem cannot be reported:

The report belongs to a package that is not installed.
```

How can I bug report steam?

Comment: What graphics are you using (you can use `lshw -C graphics`). the AMD fglrx drivers crash steam when you first launch it, so you need to switch back to the X provided normal driver (you can use Additional Drivers) when first installing it. Also, what happens when you run `steam` from terminal?

Comment: Steam I think may only support 12.04 LTS (and possibly 14.04) LTS releases ([see also](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=1504-QHXN-8366)), and 15.04 is still in development (and is off-topic here due to that) so it breaking is not surprising.

Comment: Close-voters: I'm not totally sure this should be kept open, but if we close it we'll likely end up reopening it after 15.04 is released. I don't believe the inability to report a bug in Steam with `ubuntu-bug`, in this situation, is itself a bug or a transient problem reflecting something that will be changed before release. Instead I think it pertains to [what steam package is installed](https://askubuntu.com/a/611016/22949).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you install via -Wine or without -Wine?

Anyhow I would just reinstall Steam via the terminal.

sudo apt-get install steam -y

A restart of your computer is needed.

After restart do an update.

sudo apt-get update

*As a side note I've experienced that if you are running AMD you should install steam and do updates before installing AMD drivers.*

Hope this helps.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install steam -y` I think will just tell it to install steam, which it won't if it already installed. `sudo apt-get install --reinstall steam` may be what you are after - also note on posts on SE sites you can use `code` [formatting](http://askubuntu.com/help/formatting)

Comment: Oh, and `sudo apt-get update` updates the lists of packages available, it doesn;t update stuff - you can use `sudo apt-get upgrade` to update the packages.

Comment: So it won't install steam if its installed via -Wine? That was my main question. If its installed via -Wine, it should be able to be installed within Linux but the OP doesn't specify so I am unsure. If not using -Wine then yes, --reinstall of course.

Comment: And yes, Upgrade, update go hand in hand, if you update you should probably upgrade also. Instead of correcting me on trivial things maybe put some of your knowledge on helping the OP with his issue?

Comment: Wine uses compatibility layers so may be able to get around the problem - but as it has translate stuff between the Windows program and the Linux system, reduced performance will likely result. Wine also makes a virtual windows drive in the home directory and installs the program there, it does not work like `apt-get` does. And as well as trying to help u I am seeing if steam works on my 15.04 box :)

Comment: I understand how Wine works. I just know that you can have several things installed in Wine and still install them via Linux. I do this to test compatibility within programs. To determine what is easier and what works better, performance wise. :P

Comment: I'm using the native steam client for Ubuntu.

Comment: Maybe install via Wine? Just a thought.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have a different Steam package installed than the one provided in the Ubuntu 15.04 repositories. I suspect you installed Steam on your 15.04 system with the package in the upstream (Valve) repository, by downloading the `.deb` file from http://steampowered.com or by enabling the software source for it manually.

Running `apt list -a steam` on my Ubuntu 15.04 system (where the upstream Steam repo is enabled, but Steam is not currently installed) lists:

```
steam/vivid 1:1.0.0.48-1ubuntu1 i386
steam/unknown 1.0.0.49 i386
```

If you have the version that is not from the `vivid` repository, you should not expect `ubuntu-bug` to work to report bugs for it.

To determine if this is the reason `ubuntu-bug steam` doesn't work on your system, you can examine the output of `apt-cache policy steam`, which lists repositories. (But it may not list the repository if it has been disabled since the software was installed.)

```
steam:i386:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1:1.0.0.48-1ubuntu1
  Version table:
     1:1.0.0.48-1ubuntu1 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid/multiverse i386 Packages
     1.0.0.49 0
        500 http://repo.steampowered.com/steam/ precise/steam i386 Packages
```

Since you have a `steam` package installed, the "Installed:" line will tell you which one, and you can check its origin in the version table.